# AutoHotKeys script opens Access file as read-only

Tags: ms-access, vba, autohotkey

Using AutoHotkeys to launch a Microsoft Access application in an unknown path, the script works only when the path and file name are given literally. When the script instead uses a variable, Access opens the file but as read-only.

Why? Is there a fix?

Does the script lack some permission?

The file opens normally using this:

`acc := ComObjCreate("Access.Application")`
`acc.OpenCurrentDatabase("d:\MyDatabases\MyDB.accdb")`
`acc.Visible := true`
`acc := Nothing`

The file opens read-only using this:

`MyDB := A_ScriptDir "/MyDB.accdb"`
`StringReplace,MyDB,MyDB,\,/,All`
`acc := ComObjCreate("Access.Application")`
`acc.OpencurrentDatabase(MyDB)`
`acc.Visible := true`
`acc := Nothing`

Edit:

I’ve found a substitute that works:

`MyDB := A_ScriptDir "/MyDB.accdb"`
`StringReplace,MyDB,MyDB,\,/,All`
`acc := ComObjGet(MyDB)`
`acc := Nothing`

Comment: It seems really unlikely this makes a difference, as long as `MyDB` is a valid path. Start by verifying it is.

Comment: Access could not open the correct file if the path was not valid. The file is open in a read-only state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your problem *most likely* the `StringReplace` functionality you are using.

First, `StringReplace` is a depreciated function, the current one is `StrReplace`.

Second, it looks like you are attempting to change all instances of `/` to `\`, however, this is not what you are accomplishing with that function. In fact, you are doing the opposite. What you likely meant to do was `StringReplace, MyDb, MyDb, /, \, All`.

This would change all instances of `/` to `\`, instead of `\` to `/`, which would make more sense in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Erik was right as well. Access was able to open the file using forward slashes instead of backslashes but perhaps interpreted the path as a network or Internet path instead of a local path. I'm not sure why I thought the slashes were being turned around. The script doesn't need the replacement function at all--that line can be omitted.